# How to customize a Bower package locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bower

So if i’m using a Bower package (specifically, this one: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/ ) and there’s a tiny bug in it. It’s not really a big deal, and there’s a PR for it: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/pull/645 but it seems like the PR won't be merged anytime soon... Is there a way to incorporate this fix into (at least) my local version of the package without theoretically losing all the Bower-goodness? I’m a Bower newbie. I guess I’m asking is there a way to ‘customize’ a Bower package?

(For context, I’m using Bower hooked into the Rails asset pipeline as described here:  http://dotwell.io/taking-advantage-of-bower-in-your-rails-4-app/ )

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your pain in regards to pull-requested patches :) Unfortunately, there's not really a clean way to do this.

One way to do this would be to:

1. Fork Raphel
2. Incorporate the fix you need
3. Update your bower.json to point raphel to your personal github fork`"raphael": "yourusername/rapheal#branch_name"`
4. Switch back to the "cannonical" raphel once the fix is merged

**Edit**

My original answer was given without realizing the original PR was 3 years old. I've updated to advocate for forking Raphel.

Comment: Totally makes sense. I had another friend say I should just point my `bower.json` to the already-existing fork/fix, but I think I like the idea of having it more under my control until (hopefully) the fix is incorporated into master. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped! Good luck!